Placing multiple cross-wavelet spectra plots on same window (R + WaveletComp package)
I am generating two plots, cross-wavelet power and cross-wavelet coherence, of two synthetic series x and y using the WaveletComp package in R. I'd like to modify the code below to achieve the following two objectives:

Place the two plots in one window, using a 2x1 layout with something like par(mfrow = c(2,1)), which does not seem to work here.
Move the title in each plot as a text inside the plot box with something like text(x = x, y = y, labels = "<title>"), which does not work either.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!
Code:
require(WaveletComp)

# synthetic data
x1 <- periodic.series(start.period = 1*24, length = 24*96)
x2 <- periodic.series(start.period = 2*24, length = 24*96)
x3 <- periodic.series(start.period = 4*24, length = 24*96)
x4 <- periodic.series(start.period = 8*24, length = 24*96)
x5 <- periodic.series(start.period = 16*24, length = 24*96)
x <- x1 + x2 + 3*x3 + x4 + x5 + 0.5*rnorm(24*96)
y <- x1 + x2 - 3*x3 + x4 + 3*x5 + 0.5*rnorm(24*96)

# compute cross-wavelet transform
my.data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
my.wc <- analyze.coherency(my.data, my.pair = c("x","y"),
    loess.span = 0,
    dt = 1/24, dj = 1/100,
    lowerPeriod = 1/2,
    make.pval = TRUE, n.sim = 10)

# plot cross-wavelet power
wc.image(my.wc, which.image = "wp", n.levels = 250, color.key = "i",
    main = "cross-wavelet power", plot.arrow = FALSE,
    legend.params = list(lab = "power levels"),
    timelab = "", periodlab = "period (days)")

# plot cross-wavelet coherence
wc.image(my.wc, which.image = "wc", n.levels = 250, color.key = "i",
   main = "cross-wavelet coherence", plot.arrow = FALSE,
   legend.params = list(lab = "coherence levels"),
   timelab = "", periodlab = "period (days)")



